# convert .desktop files to Debian Menu System files

Tags: debian, menu, .desktop

As I noticed more and more programs come without an entry for the Debian Menu System, but they do come at least with some .desktop file.
Is there a (ready made) way to convert these .desktop files to menu entries one can then place in ~/.menu/?

Comment: The debian menu is officially deprecated[1] since September 2015. Are there any desktop environments not supporting the .desktop files these days?

  [1]: https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2015/09/msg00000.html

Comment: The .desktop files are copied to /usr/share/applications ?

Comment: For the ones installed by the packaging system, yes that the proper location

Comment: I do not know if one would call it a Desktop environment, but e.g. the window manager IceWM does still use Debian menu (and obviously also still provides updates after September 2015 to it: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825032)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer via icewm-user list:

> If you are using 1.3.12, try
>
> $ icewm-menu-fdo >~/.icewm/menu

As this would overwrite the custom menu file, it is better to `icewm-menu-fdo > ~/.icewm/menu-fdo` and add a new line to ~/.icewm/menu: `menufile .desktop folder menu-fdo` which will show the generated entries in a new subfolder '.desktop' in the IceWM menu.
Github has the according [bbidulock/icewm repo](https://github.com/bbidulock/icewm)